# I am not getting any bar in my histogram?

Tags: python, plotly, histogram

I am trying to create monthly histogram from yearly data. I am using this code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


start,end,step = (0,14000,2000)
labels = []
bins = []
for i in range(start,end+1,step):
    bins.append(i)
    if i != end:
        labels.append(str(i)+" - "+str(i+2000))

dataset['range'] = pd.cut(dataset["TotalSales"], bins=bins, labels=labels)
df_new = dataset.groupby(["Month","range"]).count().reset_index()



import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
for i in df_new["Month"].unique():
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x = [df_new.loc[df_new["Month"]==i,"Month"],df_new.loc[df_new["Month"]==i,"range"]],
        y = df_new.loc[df_new["Month"]==i,"TotalSales"],
        name=str(i),
    ))


fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{y}', textposition='outside')
fig.update_layout(barmode='group', width=1200)
fig.show()
```

However, I am getting this blank histogram:
[image]
I want the count for each range of sales for each month.

my data is like this:

[image]

Comment: Without analysing the code (because I cannot see data); I am going to suggest you check ```hist``` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html

Comment: I have tried your code with the following test data. The graph was displayed without any problem. `dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Month': list(np.arange(1,13))*100, 'TotalSales': np.random.randint(0,15000,1200)})`

Comment: I am now getting this graph. I have edited my question

Comment: Were you able to draw a graph with my test data? What are the differences between your data and mine? Can you provide sample data?

Comment: I just edited my question: included dataset that I want to make into histogram grouped by months and bins

Comment: What is the structure of the data frame in `dataset.info()`?